# Setup AutoLayout constraints for tableHeaderView to autoresize for 3.5" screen

Tags: objective-c, ios7, storyboard, uitableview, autolayout

I need my `tableHeaderView` to be resized on 3.5" screen (height should be smaller exactly by 88 pix), but I can't add any constants for it:

[image: storyboard screenshot]

and as expected, without any constraints it do not get resized for 3.5" screen properly (it still same height).

Of course, problem can be solved by simple lines of code like:

```
if (![UIScreen isiPhone5]) {
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView.frame = CGRectMake(self.tableView.tableHeaderView.frame.origin.x, self.tableView.tableHeaderView.frame.origin.y, self.tableView.bounds.size.width, mySmallScreenHeaderHeight);
}
```

but does anybody know: is it possible to **setup auto-layout resizing for UITableViewController's tableHeaderView directly in storyboard** without putting any code? Cause it looks pretty simple and usual thing to do automatically.

I'll be appreciated for any ideas or discussions

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have gotten your header view by dragging UIView on top of UITableView, you can set the constraints. Just select this header view and choose the constraints you need by selecting orange lines which represent each constraint:

[image: constraints]

Selecting "Resize to suggested constraints" can make it easier.

Comment: Yes, I dragged UIView on the top if my UITableView. constraints are completely disabled for me, all of them.

Comment: Is your Use Autolayout box is checked?

Comment: Yes, it works perfect everywhere, except each tableHeaderView on the project's storyboard, looks like it just disabled for tableHeaderView in xCode 5.1

Comment: I have exact the same Problem, any solution for this??